# Retrieve Repsonse Code from the Request Object

Tags: symfony

I need to create a middleware app that provides an api and consumes two apis. I am currently taking data from API A and creating data to send to API B via the [HttpFoundation Request](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#request) class. However, before I take the response from API B and send it back to API A; I would like to make sure that the HTTP Status Code is 200.

I don't see the ability to check for the status code when using the Request class.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you.

Comment: You can not get status code from HTTPFoundation Request object. You have to use `GuzzleHttp\Client` or `HTTPClient`. For more info : https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html